# Which mathematical optimization problem is this?

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, operations-research

I have an combinational optimization problem and I do not know its name in literature.

My problem is the following:
I have n sets containing exclusive elements, so each element is present only in a set.
An element is characterized by 2 constraints values, and one profit.

I have to choose an element from each set in order to maximize the sum of the profits, while keeping the sum of each constraint below a a specified limit.

Is this an already studied problem? WHich is its name?
Can I assimilate it to an already studied problem?

---

Thanks to @Berthur & @mrBen replies, I discovered that this is a multiple-constrained knapsack problem where you have to create an indicator variable to force that only one element will be chosen by each set

Comment: Sounds like a variation of the Knapsack problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: @Berthur In the knapsack problem I do not have the constraint of N different sets of elements from wich I have to choose the elements. Or do you see a way that I can reduce my problem into knapsack problem ?

Comment: Hence a variation. Knapsack has 1 constraint, also summation based. So would this be a generalisation, with N constraints?

Comment: @Berthur you are right. It is a multiple-constrained knapsack problem.

Comment: Not sure, but [or.se] might be more adapted to that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're describing is know as the **multiple-choice knapsack problem**. In your case, as you have 2 constraints, it's actually a **2-dimentional multiple-choice knapsack problem**.

With the keywords **multi-dimentional multiple-choice knapsack problem** (sometime abbreviated as **MMKP**) you should be able to find the corresponding literature.